# Matlab fitcnb book type prediction

Tags: matlab, matrix, predict, naivebayes

I want to write a matlab program that will read a txt file and predict what genre type of book this txt file is (like cookbook or finance). I found the fitcnb function and wanted to use it and this is what I thought of:
-the X matrix is the learning matrix, every row represents onebook and every row represents the number of lines the word occurs in the book
-the numbers in the Y matrix represent the type of the book, so like 1 would be finance and 2 would be cookbook.

For example, in my code in the first book from the learning bundle the first word appears1 time, the second one appears two times etc.

And then the matlab program is to read the txt book, count the number of occurances in this book and use that counting vector to predict what type of book this is. This is an example of what my code look like more or less, just I have a much bigger X matrix with 41 rows and 30 columns.

```
X =[1 2 3 4 0 0 0 2;
2 3 4 1 0 0 1 0;
8 2 1 4 0 0 1 2;
0 1 0 1 4 2 8 9;
0 1 1 0 9 2 2 4;
0 0 0 1 4 4 1 6;
];


Y = [1;1;1;2;2;2;];
X = X + 0.001;

tabulate(Y);
Mdl = fitcnb(X,Y,'Distribution','mvmn');
fid = fopen('D:\ksiazki\ksiazki kucharskie\txt\1.txt','rt');

if fid < 0
    error('error loading file')
end

howMany = zeros(1,8);
oneline = fgets(fid);

ksiazka = ' ';
while ischar(oneline)

    if regexp(oneline, 'rich');
        howMany(1) = howMany(1) + 1;
    end

    *
    *
    regex ifs counting words
    *
    *    

    if regexp(oneline, 'tomato');
        howMany(8) = howMany(8) + 1;
    end


    oneline = fgets(fid);
end

fclose(fid);

howMany = howMany + 0.001;

label = predict(Mdl, howMany)
```

So my question is: is this a good strategy? My learning bundle has 30 books in it and the prediction rate isn't really good. If I make it for example 50 or 100 books, will it improve or is this strategy a bad idea?

Comment: Looks like [bag of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) which is usually a good approach. One thing missing is that you probably want to normalize your features since books vary wildly in length even in the same genre.

Comment: Did you pick the 41 words manually? Would it be meaningful to pick the words that differ most in frequency among the genres?